Need to show a popup that it is already started, when a start button is clicked in the duplicated tab
In my MVC application, I have a start button that triggers a timer when clicked. If I duplicate the page and click the start button again, the timer starts anew. How can I modify the code to display a popup indicating that the timer is already running?
@if ((Model.ISetupStatus != 3 && !Model.BIsJobFinished) && (BLSession.BIsProductionAccess || Model.objPageAccessInfo.BIsStatusUpdate))
{

Setup Section

@if (Model.ISetupStatus == 0)
{
Start
Finish
}
else if (Model.ISetupStatus == 1)
{
Stop
Finish
}
else if (Model.ISetupStatus == 2)
{
Start
Finish
}



@if(Model.BIsSetupRunning)
{
@Model.STotalSetupRunningTime
}
else if (Model.BIsSetupStopped)
{
@Model.STotalSetupTime
}
else if (Model.BIsSetupCompleted)
{
@Model.STotalSetupTime
}

Submit


}


@if ((Model.ISetupStatus != 3 && !Model.BIsJobFinished) && (BLSession.BIsProductionAccess || Model.objPageAccessInfo.BIsStatusUpdate))
{
    <div style="border: 1px solid rgb( 224, 228, 228 );border-left: 3.9px solid #d2d2d2;padding: 20px 30px;border-radius: 7px;padding-top: 12px;float:left;">
        <p>Setup Section</p>
        <div class="inner" style="border-radius:4px;display:inline-block;">
            @if (Model.ISetupStatus == 0)
            {
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:green;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,1,true,false);">Start</button>
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:#ff000052;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,3,true,true);" disabled>Finish</button>
            }
            else if (Model.ISetupStatus == 1)
            {
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:red;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,2,true,true);">Stop</button>
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:red;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,3,true,true);">Finish</button>
            }
            else if (Model.ISetupStatus == 2)
            {
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:green;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,1,true,false);">Start</button>
                <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:red;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,3,true,true);">Finish</button>
            }
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div>
            @if(Model.BIsSetupRunning)
            {
                <b id="@Model.IOrderID" style="font-size: 18px;">@Model.STotalSetupRunningTime</b>
            }
            else if (Model.BIsSetupStopped) 
            { 
                <b style="font-size: 18px;" class="blinking">@Model.STotalSetupTime</b>
            }
            else if (Model.BIsSetupCompleted) 
            {
                <b style="font-size: 18px;">@Model.STotalSetupTime</b>
            }                          
        </div>
        <p class="preview_updatebutton" style="margin-top:10px;display:none;" id="divSetupStopComments">
            <textarea id="txtSetupStopComments" class="popup-description" rows="2" cols="32" placeholder="Note misprints and or any problems for this Job"></textarea><br /><br />
            <button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;float:right;" onclick="javascript: UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,2,true,false);">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
}




Hey, you should try rearranging your question and format your code properly so it’s understandable

Check if my edit of your code is correct.

Add a JavaScript function to display the popup:
<script>
    function displayTimerRunningPopup() {
        alert('The timer is already running. Please wait until it finishes.');
    }
</script>

Modify the onclick event of the start button to check if the timer is already running before starting it:
<button class="btn production-btn" type="button" style="width:135px;background-color:green;" onclick="javascript: if(!@Model.BIsSetupRunning) UpdateProductionStatus(@Model.IJobID,1,true,false); else displayTimerRunningPopup();">Start</button>

In this modification, we're using Razor syntax @Model.BIsSetupRunning to check if the timer is already running. If it is running (BIsSetupRunning is true), the displayTimerRunningPopup() JavaScript function will be called to show a popup. Otherwise, the UpdateProductionStatus function will be called to start the timer.
I hope this will help
thanks
